# CKEditor 5 Insert text on button click - Pure JS

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I'm trying to create a sort of dropdown menu that a user can insert tokens into a CKEditor with. I've found that I can insert text in an editor with this code:

```
editorInstance.model.change( writer => {
   let pos = editorInstance.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
   writer.insertText( "TEST", pos,0);
});
```

It works when I put it in the `ClassicEditor.create.then` for testing but it does nothing when I place this in a `$().click` event. I can log something from inside the callback so I know the code is executed but nothing is inserted.

I've been trying to get this working for hours now but all the examples I can find is in angular or any other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I  Solved the issue you faced as follows

**first defined new editor that is null** and  **Then instatiate Ckeditor 5**

```
  let neditor = null;

   ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
               .then(editor => {
                   neditor = editor;
               })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
```

using pure js

```
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            var button = event.target;
            if (event.target.type === 'button' && event.target.className.includes('testtokenbutton')) {

                neditor.model.change(writer => {
                    const insertPosition = neditor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();

                    writer.insertText(button.id, insertPosition);
                });
         
            }
        });
```